# Can I animate the UIScrollView contentOffset property via its layer?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I want to zoom and scroll a UIScrollView with a CGPathRef.  Because of that I assume I have to animate the UIScrollView's layer property?  But which property would I animate that would make it equivalent to doing a UIView animation and setting its contentOffset property and zoomScale ?

These are not properties of a CALayer.

Any ideas as to how I would approach this?  Again, just want to move the scrollview to a certain contentOffset and zoomScale, but not necessarily linearly from point A to point B, zoom A to zoom B, respectively.

I was thinking a CAKeyFrameAnimation with a CGPathRef, but I don't know which properties to animate.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have to animate the `bounds` property. In fact, that's what the `contentOffset` property uses behind the scenes.

Example:

```
CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
animation.duration = 1.0;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:bounds];

bounds.origin.x += 200;

animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:bounds];

[scrollView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"bounds"];

scrollView.bounds = bounds;
```

If you're curious, the way I used to get this information is the following:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(200, 0) animated:NO];

[UIView commitAnimations];

NSLog(@"%@",scrollView);
```

The `NSLog` call will output:

```
<UIScrollView: 0x860ba20; frame = (-65.5 0; 451 367); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+RM+TM+H; animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0xec1e7c0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x860bbc0>; contentOffset: {246, 0}>
```

The `animations` snippet will list all the active animations, in this case `{ bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0xec1e7c0>; }`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had a lot of trouble getting other animation techniques (ie, block animations) to work correctly with animating my scrollView.  This worked great!

Comment: @pt2ph8 I love programmer like you, very inspiring. Pure awesomeness!

Comment: Wow, awesome catch on the bounds and contentOffset having a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a CALayer around is done by (preferably) setting it's .position property - or possibly the anchorPoint (c.f. the docs on that: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html ).

...but I don't think you want to mess with the CALayer if you're working with a UIScrollView. Have you tried applying plain CoreAnimations to your ScrollView?

(the problem is: the UIScrollView is implemented on top of CALayer - so even if you can hack it to work today, it's quite likely to break in future iOS versions. If possible, you want to avoid the CALayer for that particular class)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 4.2

This example is base on pt2ph8's `obj-c` answer.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8741283/6113158

```
var scrollView = UIScrollView()

func animateScrollView(duration: Double, to newBounds: CGRect) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
    animation.duration = duration
    animation.fromValue = scrollView.bounds
    animation.toValue = newBounds

    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeOut)

    scrollView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

    scrollView.bounds = newBounds
}
```