# iOS chaining together animations for scrolling table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

So this is a rather simple problem that I've had a rather hard time fixing. I'm trying to take advantage of table views for displaying a huge list of cells because it is already optimized for cell reuse and saves me time in that regard. I need this list to smoothly scroll at an accurate duration. If I scroll too fast cells are still loading when they show on screen so I'm only scrolling one cell at a time.

The code I'm currently using is modified from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17956396. I've changed it to only add a single animation to the array and to never remove it. Instead I have a counter that checks to see if there is another cell before scrolling.

This is working fine, but my issue is that I can't update the animation duration to be faster or slower to keep an accurate pace. Is there a way for me to chain animations in a way that would allow me to dynamically update the duration so as to keep accurate timing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8741283 this answers my question but it didn't show in my searches!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I animate the UIScrollView contentOffset property via its layer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535450/can-i-animate-the-uiscrollview-contentoffset-property-via-its-layer)